# Why can the volume go higher than 100%?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, indicator-sound, volume-control

How come the maximum volume on the sound menu isn't actually the maximum volume possible?

If I select "Sound Preferences..." and look at the volume slider in the window, it can go quite a bit higher. Why is this and what is the point? What I do know is that audio can distort past the normal 100% level in most instances but it's fine for when I'm playing DVDs.

[image]

Comment: Found a bugreport on this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+bug/659841 (maverick so it is old but it looks like it never got asigned so maybe it is a feature :D )

Comment: This one goes to 11. :)

Comment: This is not a bug. the "100%" doesn't show the current volume, it shows where the actual maximum is , in order to avoid distortion. Showing both the 100% and the current volume would fill that place with unnecessary info. One doesn't need to know the percentage of the current volume, he/she just needs to have a volume as loud as his/her needs require.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting from 9.10 Pulse Audio merges the sound mixing from ALSA. This has the side effect that you are able to increase the sound level to >100% if you need to. This of course goes on the cost of sound quality as pcm sound will get distorted when overamplified. You can [disable this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32383/adjust-pcm-volume/32423#32423) behaviour in PulseAudio if you want.

Or, on Ubuntu > 16.04, whether the Sound Settings control panel volume slider allows setting the volume above 100% is controlled by the following dconf key. Run the following command to disallow setting the volume above 100%. Change takes effect immediately.

```
dconf write com/ubuntu/sound/allow-amplified-volume false
```

This setting can also be done from the **dconf-editor**:

[image]

Comment: Any updates? since 18.04 `No such schema “com.ubuntu.sound”`

Comment: @cat ther is. See edit

Comment: In 18.04 the key exists and is writable but i think it doesn't cause `gnome-control-center` to allow volumes over 100%

Comment: `dconf write /com/ubuntu/sound/allow-amplified-volume false`

Answer (score 5):

Overamplifying a volume is a good feature, especially for laptops where internal speakers are not loud. I was using this feature since Ubuntu (9.10) on my FujitsuSiemens SI1520. It helped me very much to listen to music. You can even more amplify a sound by using the VLC player where you can gain up 200% of normal sound level :)

Comment: If your source audio (e.g. music) is properly produced, it will be already normalized meaning it's audio form will exceed -3 dB and cannot be boosted without very bad distortion (basically a noise that sounds like your speakers are going to rip). Going over 100% only makes sense for poor quality source audio which is incorrectly recorded or mixed.

Answer (score 2):

I use it when i listen to speeches that were recorded at rather low volume. It might distort music/sound effects etc but it is rather useful in those cases when you just can't listen because of bad recording.

100% is the actual maximum volume - 125 (if i recall correctly) is the volume they thought that would give you loud enough sound without too much distortion.

Most players provide the same feature - smplayer's "max amplification" (with 110 as default) for example