# Windows vs Ubuntu - Audio Quality

Tags: 11.10, sound, windows

Someone help with this one...

My notebook have a dual-boot... Win7 and Ubuntu...

i've this doubt unexplained until this week (I pray):

Why the "Window's audio" is so much better than "ubuntu", i've already tested with third party audio systems, and even in my laptop, the diference is so "scary"...

I was wondering, if there is someway to decrease these disadvantage...

Comment: A question about hardware / drivers comparison is not much of a question without some description of your hardware (namely your sound hardware). Please add that information to your question be pressing the *edit* button.

Comment: The only thing you can do to get good sound quality on Ubuntu is to replace ALSA and PulseAudio with OSSv4 (with production quality resampler). I've posted instructions how to do that in this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103660/ubuntu-11-10-vs-windows-7-music-quality) which regards the same topic.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using an equalizer like I do. `pulseaudio-equalizer` is a global eq and sounds wicked (imho).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the Pulse Audio Equalizer do? I have my entire soundtrack collection in FLAC to get great sound quality, and I'd love anything that would improve it.

Comment: its an equalizer, with presets.  For me at least, it enhances my standard laptop speakers, which aren't standard at all, not in windows.  They are JBL SRS

Comment: I'll try, but with not a lot of faith... MS system has a good quality without any tricks, and i'm wondering why, I just can't understand why this things are so diferente. :S

Answer (score 1):

Did you try lowering the volume? I've noticed that in Ubuntu audio may be over-amplified causing a distortion. Try around 70% that might help you.

Comment: See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/41348/3940)

Comment: Thank you 4 yr answer, but... I'vre tried all simple changes in ubuntu, without install any third packages, and theres nothign to compare, the MS system has a audio much much better with the same volume sound.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you get better sound experience in linux (ubuntu) than the windows7's. In your case this is not as I am claiming so you should find the problem in the driver or in the hardware. But if you just say "better" because of the SRS tech in the WindowsMediaPlayer well then this is another thing....
SRS, srs wow, surround and all other sound enhancing technologies are NOT FREE (actually pretty expensive, charging monthly for usage) and the Linux is a Free OS so there's no way companies providing sound experience (like the SRS) have no way to get their money, so they consider not to throw their software/hardware for free for everybody and this is pretty normal :>

I apersonally use the PulseAudio Equalizer for linux just with two simple tweaks I get better experience than the windows7's with srs_sandbox.

But if you can't fix hardware/drivers issue; PulseAudio EQ doesn't work (well) for you; and you really need to "tweak" the music you play, you could try downloading WINAMP 2.95 and running it with wINE. After that go to WINAMP.COM > PLUGINS and find "enhancer" (it's a green square on the picture with 7-8 sliders). This should give you SRS-Like experience but ONLY in the WINAMP APP.
Another (more advanced) plugin for winamp is JAMMIX which is kind'a complicated at first look, but It does the most compressing/equalizing/tubing effects like 'center' 'bass' '3d' 'reverb' 'surround' 'ProLogic' experience and so.
H

But at all my opinion is you should get another audio hardware (sound card) 
Hope I helped