# Disable Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 sound amplicifation

Tags: sound

I've got a small problem with sound amplification. I use the volume-buttons on my keyboard a lot (much closer than the volume button of my sound system). When I press the volume up key, the overall system sound goes beyond the 100% amplification bar. Thus, i get incredible bad sound. I really don't like that.

I've read some possibilities to fix this, but the answers are a bit messy.

So, therefore, is it possible to disable sound amplification completely? And how do I do that?

In the sound dialog box I can change the output-volume, but that's it. I can't set the max volume output.

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try to fix that issue. It really depends on a set of particularities of your sound card and Linux drivers. But you can try this:

- Take a look at this question: [Adjust PCM volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32383/adjust-pcm-volume) The master and PCM volumes referred in that question are set with `alsamixer`.
- Install pavucontrol and see if any options help: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Comment: Hmm.. I think pavucontrol did the trick :) I set it to 100% and it stays there, even when I use the keyboard keys :) Thx for the help!