# Alsamixer or Pulseaudio reverts PCM channel level to 100% in 14.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, rhythmbox

Why does the PCM slider go up to 100% every time I change volume with media keys, or restart my Dell E1405? How do I make it stay at 81% (which is one step below the red line)?

Answer (score 5):

The [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32383/adjust-pcm-volume) solved the problem:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
```

and change:

```
[Element PCM]
volume = merge
```

to:

```
[Element PCM]
volume = ignore
```

Note that a reboot is required for this to take hold.