# Reduce maximum volume in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

I want to be able to change the volume from a range of 0% to 40%. Cap it there permanently.

Sometimes depending on the program I'm running, the audio get resetted resulting in a full blast of 100% volume in my headphones.

I tried using different commands.
pactl, pacmd, and sink-volume commands, but nothing came as expected.

Thanks in advance if anyone knows how to do this! Google doesn't give out any solution as I've searched a lot.

Comment: You mentioned the exact programs that should do you what you want. I am not sure what you mean by `nothing came as expected`. Perhaps you should create a script that you run when required...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to create scripts. I barely can manage commands. Those I listed are commands found, used mostly to read info about the volume/device/driver,  or change the dB volume, but can't limit it permanently.

Comment: No problem, putting the proper commands in a script is no problem. It is just surprising that when you change the values with the Volume Control tool they somehow change back... Unfortunately I cannot replay your configuration as the headphones port is not working in my laptop.

Comment: No problem, I'm keep researching a little bit and the problem lies in alsamixer. PCM=100 and Front=100 are desired values. On the other side if Master goes up more than 30... starts getting really loud. I'll try to find options to limit Master.

Comment: Perhaps you can play with these settings:  Increase volume by 5%

`amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+`

Decrease volume by 5%

`amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-`

Set volume to 50%

`amixer -D pulse sset Master 50%`

Comment: I'm new to scripting, but the idea is to tell alsamixer if the volume is higher than 40%, then go to 40%

`function get_volume()
{
mixer=$(amixer get Master | egrep -o "[0-9]+%")
echo number is $mixer 
}`

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: I found `amixer get Master` give a different output than `amixer -D pulse sget Master` where the separate channels are concerned. I will have a go at a script, be right back...

Comment: No problem. I'll keep on checking stuff to do. Thanks for replying!

Some people claim that alsamixer won't save a configuration permanently, and PCM shouldn't be as high as it is (100%).

Comment: There are multiple workarounds, but none is as effective as this one I just found:
[Adjust PCM volume?](https://askubuntu.com/a/32423/690527)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
Lines=$(amixer -D pulse sget Master | grep '[0-9]%' | awk '{printf "%s\n",$5}')

set -- $Lines
lVol=$(echo "$1" | tr -cd [:digit:])
rVol=$(echo "$2" | tr -cd [:digit:])

if ((lVol>rVol))
then hVol=$lVol
else hVol=$rVol
fi

maxVol=40
if ((hVol>maxVol))
then
  echo "One or both channels too loud, setting both to $maxVol"
  amixer -D pulse sset Master ${maxVol}%
fi
# EOF #
```